# Double Loops in R: Use .name_repair to specify repair?

Tags: r, loops

I have this dataset in R:

```
set.seed(123)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

col1 = myFun(100)
col2 = myFun(100)
col3 = myFun(100)
col4 = myFun(100)
group <- c("A","B","C","D")
group = sample(group, 100, replace=TRUE)

example = data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, group)

       col1       col2       col3       col4 group
1 SKZDZ9876D BTAMF8110T LIBFV6882H ZFIPL4295E     A
2 NXJRX7189Y AIZGY5809C HSMIH4556D YJGJP8022H     C
3 XPTZB2035P EEKXK0873A PCPNW1021S NMROS4134O     A
4 LJMCM3436S KGADK2847O SRMUI5723N RDIXI7301N     B
5 ADITC6567L HUOCT5660P AQCNE3753K FUMGY1428B     D
6 BAEDP8491P IAGQG4816B TXXQH6337M SDACH5752D     C
```

I wrote this loop that compares different string distance metrics between all combinations of (col1,col2) and (col3,col4):

```
method = c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram", "cosine", "jaccard", "jw","soundex")

library(stringdist)

results = list()

for (i in 1:length(method))

{

method_i = method[i]
name_1_i = paste0("col1_col_2", method_i)
 name_2_i = paste0("col3_col_4", method_i)

p1_i = stringdistmatrix(col1, col2, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
            as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
            pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_1_i)

p2_i = stringdistmatrix(col3, col4, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
            as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
            pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_2_i)

p1_i = p1_i[,3]
p2_i = p2_i[,3]

final_i = cbind(p1_i, p2_i)

results[[i]] = final_i
}

final = do.call(cbind.data.frame, results)
final = cbind(col1,col2, col3,col4, final)

average_col1_col2_dist = (final$col1_col_2osa  + final$col1_col_2lv + final$col1_col_2dl      + final$col1_col_2hamming + final$col1_col_2lcs +     final$col1_col_2qgram  + final$col1_col_2cosine    + final$col1_col_2jaccard + final$col1_col_2jw   + final$col1_col_2soundex)/10

 average_col3_col4_dist =  ( final$col3_col_4osa     +    final$col3_col_4lv       +     final$col3_col_4dl  +     final$col3_col_4hamming +  final$col3_col_4lcs +  final$col3_col_4qgram  +   final$col3_col_4cosine +    final$col3_col_4jaccard  +    final$col3_col_4jw     +   final$col3_col_4soundex)/10

final = data.frame( col1, col2, col3, col4, average_col1_col2_dist,  average_col3_col4_dist)
final = scale(final)
```

**Now, I would like to make this a "double loop" and have the same comparisons being done, but the comparisons should be made only within each "group" :**

```
results = list()


for (i in 1:length(method))
for (j in 1:length(unique(example$group))

{

{

groups_j = unique(example$group[j])
my_data_i = file[which(file$fsa == groups_j  ), ]


method_i = method[i]
name_1_i = paste0("col1_col_2", method_i)
 name_2_i = paste0("col3_col_4", method_i)

p1_i = stringdistmatrix(my_data_i$col1, my_data_i$col2, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
            as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
            pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_1_i)

p2_i = stringdistmatrix(my_data_i$col3, my_data_i$col4, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
            as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
            pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_2_i)

p1_i = p1_i[,3]
p2_i = p2_i[,3]

final_i = cbind(p1_i, p2_i)
 results[[i]] = final_i

}
   
}

final = do.call(cbind.data.frame, results)
final = cbind(col1,col2, col3,col4, final)

average_col1_col2_dist = (final$col1_col_2osa  + final$col1_col_2lv + final$col1_col_2dl      + final$col1_col_2hamming + final$col1_col_2lcs +     final$col1_col_2qgram  + final$col1_col_2cosine    + final$col1_col_2jaccard + final$col1_col_2jw   + final$col1_col_2soundex)/10

 average_col3_col4_dist =  ( final$col3_col_4osa     +    final$col3_col_4lv       +     final$col3_col_4dl  +     final$col3_col_4hamming +  final$col3_col_4lcs +  final$col3_col_4qgram  +   final$col3_col_4cosine +    final$col3_col_4jaccard  +    final$col3_col_4jw     +   final$col3_col_4soundex)/10

final = data.frame( col1, col2, col3, col4, average_col1_col2_dist,  average_col3_col4_dist)
final = scale(final)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error:
! Column 1 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names can't be empty.
x Empty name found at location 1.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Avoid the outer loop altogether.  Put your inner loop in a function.  Then use `group_map` to apply your inner loop.  Something like `example %>% group_by(group) %>% group_map(myInnerLoopFun)`.  In R, a good rule of thumb is "If I'm thinking of using a `for` loop, there is probably a better way of doing it".  I think this is a case in point.

Comment: Wasn't it possible edit your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74556695/6574038) to include this problem? Seems very much related.

Comment: @ Limey: thanks! if you have time, could you please show an example?

Comment: @ jay.sf : thanks! i can delete the first question if necessary - I was not sure if the approach I was using was correct. thanks!

Comment: @jay.sf :any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the process of trying to understand what you're doing, I drifted pretty far from your original code. There isn't anything necessarily wrong with the majority of it!

##### Your code

As far as your grouping code...

You started with

```
for(this in that) 
   for(this in that)
   {
       {
```

The brackets nest what's *inside* the for statement. You need to

```
for(this in that) {
   for(this in that) {

# or this works
for(this in that) 
   {
   for(this in that)
      {
```

When you specified your `for` criteria, you went with integers. However, you could just go with the string, as in

```
for(i in method) { # i is a string

# versus

for(i in 1:length(method)) { # i is an integer
```

When you wrote the nested `for` statement you missed a closing parenthesis.

```
for(j in 1:length(unique(example$group)) # end parentheses missing!

# should have been

for(j in 1:length(unique(example$group)))

# easier to see like this:

for(j in 1:length(
                  unique(
                         example$group
                        )
                  )
    )
```

> Did you know? You can set RStudio to use 'Rainbow parentheses' which is great for ensuring you don't miss closing parentheses or brackets. Go to Tools -> Global Options -> Code (left menu in popup) -> Display (top menu in menu popup) & 'Rainbow parentheses' is the last item in the list. This is what it looks like with my current appearance settings:
> [image]

When extracting the group, you selected a dataset row, not a unique value.

```
# this selects jth row, then looks for unique values
groups_j = unique(example$group[j]) 

# you need to get the unique values, then iterate
group_j = unique(example$group)[j] 

# the j goes outside the call for unique()
```

In this code, you wrote `file` and `file$fsa`. I'm assuming this is equivalent to `example` and `example$group`, because I don't have whatever is in `file`.

All of these lines of code do the same thing. Keep in mind that `group` is in the data frame, but it's an object in the environment on its own, as well.

```
my_data_i = example[which(example$group == group_j), ] # this would work
my_data_i <- filter(example, groups == group_j)        # this would work
my_data_i <- example[group == group_j, ]               # this would work
my_data_i <- example[example$group == group_j, ]       # this would work
```

If you iterated over groups instead of indices, you can skip the creation of `group_j` which is the only time you used `j`.

```
for(j in unique(example$group)) {
    my_data_i <- example[example$group == j, ]
}
```

When you sent the results using `i` and `i` alone, you would overwrite the data with each iteration over `j`.

The first group iteration can go in `results[[i]]`, but the next `group`, can either be bound to that data or placed in a list within a list.

For example:

```
results[[1]] <- group 1, method 1
results[[1]] <- rbind(results[[1]], [group 2, method 1])

# or 

results[[1]][[1]] <- group 1, method 1
results[[1]][[2]] <- group 2, method 1
```

Considering those two options for the lists (above), the first will allow your remaining code (creation of final, averages, etc.) to work without any changes. However, if you use the second option (above), that code will require modification.

If you leave `for(j` with `1:length` this will work:

```
if(j < 2) {
  results[[i]] <- final_i
} else {
  results[[i]] <- rbind(results[[i]], final_i) 
}
```

If you use `for(j in unique(example$group))`, you could use this:

```
if(isTRUE(j == unique(example$group)[1])) { # isTRUE() to avoid null errors 
  results[[i]] <- final_i
} else {
  results[[i]] <- rbind(results[[i]], final_i) 
}
```

Your nested `for` statements all in one chunk.

```
results = list()
for (i in 1:length(method)) {  # bracket missing here; it was in the wrong place
  for (j in 1:length(unique(example$group))) { # missing a parentheses here
    # { # this needs to be after each for statement
    
    # groups_j = unique(example$group[j]) # you have selected the jth row, not the jth unique
    
    group_j = unique(example$group)[j] # the selection goes outside the call for unique()
    # use things like print or message to check what your function does
    # print(group_j)
    # message('this is a message ', group_j) # notice the different color in the console?
    
    my_data_i <- example[group == group_j, ] # this would work
    
    method_i = method[i]
    name_1_i = paste0("col1_col_2", method_i)
    name_2_i = paste0("col3_col_4", method_i)
    
    p1_i = stringdistmatrix(my_data_i$col1, my_data_i$col2, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
      as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
      pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_1_i)
    
    p2_i = stringdistmatrix(my_data_i$col3, my_data_i$col4, method =  method_i, useNames = "string") %>%
      as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
      pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = name_2_i)
    
    p1_i = p1_i[,3]
    p2_i = p2_i[,3]
    
    final_i = cbind(p1_i, p2_i)
    
    # results[[i]] = final_i # you replace this content everytime you change groups
    # you need to append the values between groups (assuming you want one column per test type)
    # first append, then combine
    if(j < 2) { # use < instead of == to avoid null error
      results[[i]] <- final_i
    } else {
      results[[i]] <- rbind(results[[i]], final_i) 
    }
  } 
}
```

##### My code to accomplish the same task

I've added a few checks and balances to make it more dynamic. You can send any number of columns, methods, or groups to `grpComp`.

This uses `tidyverse`, `glue`, and `stringdist`.

This first function is called by the other function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)
library(glue)

strD <- function(c1, c2, mm) { # input column 1; column 2; measurement method
  res <- stringdistmatrix(c1, c2, method = mm, useNames = 'string')
  f_res <- matrix(res) # extract values and flatten
}
```

This is the distances by group function.

```
grpComp <- function(fr, methods, grp) { # data frame of columns to compare,
  # methods to use, groups (vector same length as df rows)
  cnames <- names(fr)
  if(length(cnames) %% 2 != 0) {
    message('there are an uneven number of columns to compare')
    break # something's wrong
  }
  if(length(grp) != nrow(fr)) {
    message('there groups vector length must match number of rows in the data')
    break # something's wrong
  }
  # extract distances
  dists <- map(
    method, 
    function(j) {
      str_ds <- map_dfc(    # by column sets  
        seq(from = 1, to = length(cnames), by = 2),
        function(i) {
          str_gr <- map_dfr( # by group
            unique(grp),
            function(k) {
              as.data.frame(list(  # has to be list for `col.names` to work
                strD(fr[grp == k, cnames[i]],
                     fr[grp == k, cnames[i + 1]], j)), 
                optional = F, row.names = NULL, 
                col.names = paste0("c", i, i+1, '_', j))
            })        # combine groups by rows
          str_gr
        })            # combine methods by columns
      str_ds
    }) %>% do.call(cbind, .)
  ncnames <- names(dists) %>% substr(1, 3) %>% unique() # determine unique col groups
  for(m in ncnames) { # get averages for each comparison set
    dists <- mutate(dists, 
                    "ave_{m}" := rowMeans(across(contains(m))) %>% scale())
  }
  dists <- select(dists, contains('ave'))
}
```

This is how you would use this code.

```
test5 <- grpComp(example[, 1:4], methods, example$group)
```

Even though your function for non-grouped data is working, I thought I would include that code as well.

```
strComp <- function(fr, methods) { # data frame of columns to compare, methods to use
  cnames <- names(fr)
  if(length(cnames) %% 2 != 0) {
    message('there are an uneven number of columns to compare')
    break # something's wrong
  }
  # extract distances
  dists <- map(
    method, 
    function(j) {
      str_ds <- map_dfc(
        seq(from = 1, to = length(cnames), by = 2),
        function(i) {
          as.data.frame(list(  # has to be list for `col.names` to work
            strD(fr[, cnames[i]], fr[, cnames[i + 1]], j)), optional = F, 
            col.names = paste0("c", i, i+1, '_', j))
        })
      str_ds
    }) %>% do.call(cbind, .)
  ncnames <- names(dists) %>% substr(1, 3) %>% unique() # determine unique col groups
  for(k in ncnames) { # get averages for each comparison set
    dists <- mutate(dists, 
                    "ave_{k}" := rowMeans(across(contains(k))) %>% scale())
  }
  dists <- select(dists, contains('ave'))
}
```

To use this function:

```
test4 <- strComp(example[, 1:4], methods)
```

Comment: @ Kat: Thank you so much! If you are interested - here is a related question I posted about the mathematical validity of this approach! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583994/averaging-distances-valid-comparasions

Comment: is there any way  you can help me fix the original code I had written? I was trying to learn about setting up "double loops in R" ... thank you so much!

Comment: I've edited my answer. It now starts with a review of your code!

Comment: @ Kat: thank you so much! in a few hours, I will be able to accept your answer! I have been trying to keep working on this example ... I posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588055/loop-index-is-being-ignored-in-r .... do you have any ideas about this? Thanks!